# iterate row by row COUNTIF using ArrayFormula on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, countif, array-formulas

I am trying to iterate a COUNTIF formula that counts the number of cells in each row containing numbers greater than 4. I am trying to use ArrayFormula to do this but it isn't working.

Unfortunately it counts ALL the cells matching the condition across the entire range B2:G39 resulting in 26 being entered in each row of column K rather than row by row count i.e. number of cells >4 in B2:G2 entered in K2, number of cells >4 in B3:G3 entered in K3

This is the formula

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(arrayformula( if( row(H:H)=1, "Number of cells >4",COUNTIF(A2:G39,">4"))),39,1)
```

Here is a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eG5yaVwH8ODfaZEZWviEIEVLEEC9L76kJFiyeyJH3i4/edit?usp=sharing) that includes sample data and my formula

Comment: Similar Q is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147713/arrayformula-countif-each-row-separately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARRAYFORMULA COUNTIF each row separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147713/arrayformula-countif-each-row-separately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try entering this in cell K2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),IFERROR(1/0),MMULT(SIGN(A2:G>4),SIGN(TRANSPOSE(A2:G2)))))
```

By putting your data into matrix form, you can use the [MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en) and [SIGN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093513?hl=en) functions with ARRAYFORMULA to achieve the conditional count over rows you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Greg. that worked! Why does my formula not work? Curious to understand arrayformulas limitations

Comment: My pleasure, @herteladrian. Your formula, reduced to `=arrayformula(COUNTIF(A2:G39,">4"))` for ease of discussion, doesn't work because the range argument `A2:G39` is "commandeered" by the COUNTIF function and used in its computation, returning a result that is not an array. In other words, ARRAYFORMULA never sees the input range, so it has no chance to substitute for it. This is why ARRAYFORMULA does not work with AND and OR functions also.

Answer (score 4):

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=501581326)

I found that `mmult` is very slow and may cause your file loading a long time. I suggest using `len` + `join` (with a query) instead (speed is not tested):

```
={"RegexReplace-Len..."; ArrayFormula(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(--(A2:P>5),A2:A<>"")),,100500)),"[ 0]", "")))}
```

Also here's a [solution by JPV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173391/5372400):

```
=filter(COUNTIF(IF(A2:P>5, ROW(A2:A)), ROW(A2:A)), A2:A<>"")
```

Change `A2:P` to your range, `A2:A` to a key column with no blank cells.