# ARRAYFORMULA COUNTIF each row separately

Tags: google-sheets

I try to `COUNTIF(B2:Q2;">5")` for each row and return the result for each row in column `A` but I clearly fail on using `ARRAYFORMULA` for this purpose.

Could you help?

Comment: Similar Q is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707078/iterate-row-by-row-countif-using-arrayformula-on-google-sheets

Comment: @MaxMakhrov how could I get your solution to work with my countif formula below, where I'm counting the instances of TRUE across a range of cells in a row? I tried plugging it into yours but couldn't get it to work. =COUNTIF(U5:X5,"'TRUE")>=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Sample File**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=501581326)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(FILTER(--(B2:Q>5),B2:B<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:Q)^0)))`

`mmult` is effective, but slow formula. I used `filter` to limit the number of calculations.

**Edit.** Here's another formula to do the same:

`=ArrayFormula(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(--(B2:Q>5),B2:B<>"")),,100500)),"0", "")," ","")))`

Looks clunky but should work faster (not tested).

Comment: Thank you, Max! This is truly a load of formula! :)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Max's solution, I believe it should be possible to use COUNTIF(). See if this works

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(IF(B2:Q>5,ROW(B2:B)), ROW(B2:B)))
```

Comment: It works perfectly! It's smart to use `ROW` for this.