# Check row by row COUNTIF using ArrayFormula on Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, countif

I am trying to make a basic countif function which is `=COUNTIF(C2:BE2,"Yes")` into an ArrayFunction which is

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A2:A),"",countif(C:BE,"Yes")
```

But this function counts every single "Yes" in the range `C:BE`.

How do I make it so it counts row by row and still is an array formula?

Meaning the cell with this function counts from C2:BE2 and the next one counts from C3:BE3

Also I can't use the sign function as it only works if the criteria has numbers in it which the other posts in this forum have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterate row by row COUNTIF using ArrayFormula on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707078/iterate-row-by-row-countif-using-arrayformula-on-google-sheets)

Comment: Have you tried putting C2:BE2  or C2:BE into your `countif`?

Comment: yup did that. It counts all the yes's in C2:BE

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to MMULT (see Max's link), try entering in row 2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), countif(if(C2:BE="Yes", row(C2:C)), row(C2:C)),))
```

Comment: Hi JPV, Thanks for the response but your forumla isn't working. The sheet keeps trying to load the formula but is not loading it or processing it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a3-DzI8gC5xfMEGqhr8ixkbK6Rn-Y9i4l9s8kTC055k/edit?usp=sharing 
The formula needs to be in sheet 2

Comment: Hi, you currently have +15000 rows. If you cut down the number of rows and enter in BF1 ={"Total No. of Yes"; ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), countif(if(C2:BE="Yes", row(C2:C)), row(C2:C)),))} you should be okay.

Comment: Hi JPV, I can't thank you enough. That worked! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @UzumakiNavin: most welcome. Please 'accept' the answer or upvote if the provided formula helped you out.

Comment: Hi @JPV could you please help with a similar item: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105388/counting-incrementing-decrementing-in-google-sheets-using-arrayformula-countif