# Using ArrayFormula to countif multiple columns and output the sum on each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, gs-vlookup

I've created a dense formula using COUNTIF and VLOOKUP across multiple columns, and I've currently set it up so that I have to copy/paste every formula. But I'd really like to be able to use arrayformula to write the formula once for each of the columns below, and have it render across at least 1000 rows. Is there a trick to writing this?

Column 1

```
=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(F3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Defense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(G3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Defense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(H3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Defense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(I3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Defense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(J3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Defense*")
```

Column 2

```
=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(F3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Offense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(G3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Offense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(H3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Offense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(I3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Offense*")
+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(J3,WarLinesValuesTypes,2,FALSE),"*Offense*")
```

I also saw the StackOverflow post here ([iterate row by row COUNTIF using ArrayFormula on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707078/iterate-row-by-row-countif-using-arrayformula-on-google-sheets)), and tried to emulate it, but I am not getting it right. My sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JR_eYvmf6YgW0CfzHrSR6dxF8RmyWhSKhqSpRnnbipk/edit?usp=sharing) shows the complex formula working correctly for both columns, as well as my failed attempt for 1 of those columns as a trial using arrayformula, mmult, and sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 INDIRECT("F2:J"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1), 'Flattened Standard War Lines'!A:B, 2, 0)), 
 ".*Offense.*"), 1, 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(F:J))^0))
```

[image]